# How to access meteor app from outside without passing through NginX?

Tags: node.js, nginx, meteor

I am hosting a meteor app on an Ubunu Linux machine. The app is listening on port `3000`. If I use a webserver, like NginX and forwards the HTTP requests from port `80` to `3000` I can browse to the server from the outside and see reach the app. However, when I try to access the app directly at port `3000`, i.e. browse http://myhost:3000 it just tries to connect and nothing happens.

I have made sure that all firewalls are down and that the app is listening on all interfaces, i.e. `0.0.0.0:3000`, so that is not the issue.

To verify that port was actually reachable, I created a simple node js webserver:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write('Hello World!');
  res.end();
}).listen(3000);
```

Now browsing to the the sever, I can see `"Hello World!"`. So obviously this works so why I can not reach meteor has nothing to do with firewalls or unopened ports.

Thus it seems that there is something strange when trying to access a meteor app directly at port 3000. But why? I use the following environment variables:

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor
export HOST=myhost
export PORT=3000
export ROOT_URL=http://myhost
```

So what am I missing? Ports are open and I can see that the `node` process instance is listening on port `3000` when I run `netstat -tulpan`

Comment: Are you following [this nginx recipe](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-js-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-nginx#step-1-—-setting-up-an-nginx-web-server) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the `force-ssl` meteor package which makes a redirect back to the `ROOT_URL` without port number. So solution is to remove the package to make it work with a custom port.

I was discussing the solution on the meteor forum where I got the solution:
https://forums.meteor.com/t/can-not-access-meteor-app-without-passing-through-nginx-server/40739/11